# External CSS in Laravel 5.2 project

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

I am currently using Laravel 5.2  framework for my web dev project and stuck on problem. In my dashboard.blade.php i want specify the link to an external css file which is in public/src/css/main.css.
I used URL::to() and URL::asset() methods to get the  absolute path to the CSS file  but still it is not working.
When i placed my CSS file just inside the public directory everything worked fine but when i place it inside any subdirectory in the public directory it doesnot work.
I am homestead along with the laravel as development environment.

[image: dashboard.blade.php file]
dashboard.blade.php file

[image: directory structure of the project]

directory structure of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter where you place your css file inside `public` folder you can get it using the code :

```
<link rel=stylesheet" href="{{asset('src/css/main.css')}}">
```

For this code place your css file inside `public/src/css`

In your image of directory there is no folder as `css` inside `src`

Answer (score 1):

Please put your css in public folder

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css')}}">
```